# No microphone with Sony WH 1000-MX3 and Broadcom BCM2045 Bluetooth on Fedora

Tags: bluetooth

I have a ThinkPad X220 with a [Broadcom BCM2045](https://www.broadcom.com/products/wireless/bluetooth-socs/bcm2045) Bluetooth module. The [Sony WH 1000-XM3](https://www.sony.de/electronics/kopfband-kopfhoerer/wh-1000xm3) wireless headphones work just fine with my phone, I can listen to music and make calls (microphone working). When coupled to the laptop running Fedora 31, it only registers as an audio playback device but I cannot seem to use its microphone. In Pulse Audio Control (`pavucontrol`) it just does not show up.

From the [data sheet of the Broadcom card](https://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/175091/BOARDCOM/BCM2045/384/1/BCM2045.html) I see that it supports bluetooth in versions 1.1, 1.2 and 2.0+EDR. From the [specs for the headphones](https://www.sony.de/electronics/kopfband-kopfhoerer/wh-1000xm3/specifications) I can only find that it supports Bluetooth 4.2. My phone specs also list Bluetooth 4.2 and A2DP, so they seem to get along perfectly.

I did not hear a difference in sound quality between phone and laptop, but I did not try yet. Is is correct that my laptop talks to my headphones in some some older version of the Bluetooth protocol such that they can get some basic audio but perhaps not in the better A2DP variant? And there is just nothing I can do except buying a new Bluetooth module for my laptop?